# Android custom brush

Tags: android, paint

I'm developing an android paint application.

how can I create a custom brush (e.g `watercolor brush`)  for android? can someone give me some example? or any explanation?

Answer (score -1):

If you have downloaded Android SDK, it comes with API demos that include several small applications that will illustrate the use of the Android APIs. One of the examples is [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html). I hope you can gain ideas from it.

Comment: Which one of those projects did you mean?

Comment: Am so sorry. I guess they changed the content of the link where it has supposed to have the samples. I'm not sure where they are located right now but what I was referring to was the FingerPaint sample in API Demos.